# What to do after signing in with apple?

Tags: ios, authentication

My backend uses a standard email and password for login.

After getting the ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential information, I have a user identifier for the email portion of the email and password based login. What would I use for the password when creating a new account in my system?

```
if let credential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
    let userIdentifier = credential.user
    let identityToken = credential.identityToken
    let authCode = credential.authorizationCode
    let realUserStatus = credential.realUserStatus

    // Create account in your system
}
```

Comment: You will need to change your authentication process on your server. When sign in with Apple is used your server needs to validate the authorisation grant code that your app received with Apple's server in order to receive a session token.  Validating the grant code may trigger MFA. Once the user has responded your server will receive a session token from Apple. At this point you can consider the user "signed in". There is no need to further validate a username/password. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi

Comment: @Paulw11 I have a problem when I use the authorization code, I send it to my server, and it got an error response `invalid_grand.` I don't know why because I sent it to the server immediately when I catch it from delegate